# Getting ANR while scrolling list of videos in Moto G4

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, android-anr-dialog

I have got ANR while scrolling the list of ExoPlayer videoView, This ANR is produced only on MotoG4 device(I have tested more than 15 devices with different OS and I found this ANR on Moto G4 OS 7.0).

```
ANR in com.it.myapp.debug (com.it.myapp.debug/com.it.myapp.activity.ExploreActivity)
                                      PID: 24035
                                      Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 58.  Wait queue head age: 5509.1ms.)
                                      Load: 5.6 / 4.82 / 4.17
                                      CPU usage from 223502ms to 0ms ago
```

Where is the problem? And why it happens?

Comment: First you need to know why ANR occur if you know then you know why it occur while scrolling..

Comment: @duggu It happens on Moto G4 device only.

Comment: i understand bcz i read your question very well so my question is that u know ANr ?

Comment: Please refer: "It might be due to any long operation being performed on the UI thread, which is not good.
This might be block the UI thread for further computation.
All the long operations must be perform on the background thread.
This also depends on the Devices, some devices does not show this issue while performing long operation in UI thread, but doing this in background thread is recommended."

Comment: please share the code or lines which produces ANR

Comment: @Cansel What I only get it from console is this :------- 02-20 12:18:15.464 E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.it.smyapp.debug (com.it.myapp.debug/com.it.myapp.activity.ExploreActivity)
                                      PID: 24035
                                      Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 8.  Wait queue head age: 5766.3ms.)
                                      Load: 5.52 / 5.05 / 4.39